# Prestashop / You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances

Tags: php, pdo, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

This is my error : You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances

in syncorder.php line 307

```
at PDO->__sleep()

at serialize(array('origine' => 'Order of Giga-Cultures', 'order' => object(Order), 'customer' => object(Customer), 'delivery' => object(Address), 'invoice' => object(Address), 'order_carrier' => object(OrderCarrier), 'paiements' => object(PrestaShopCollection), 'message' => object(Message), 'order_details' => array(object(OrderDetail)), 'cart' => object(Cart), 'transporteur' => 'Mondial Relais'))
in syncorder.php line 307
```

This is my line 307 :

```
$reponse=$this->post(
                $lien,array(
                    'data'=>base64_encode(serialize(
                        array(
                            'origine'=>$this->l('Order of ').Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_NAME'),
                            'order'=>$order,
                            'customer'=>$customer,
                            'delivery'=>$delivery,
                            'invoice'=>$invoice,
                            'order_carrier'=>$order_carrier,
                            'paiements'=>$paiements,
                            'message'=>$message,
                            'order_details'=>$order_details,
                            'cart'=>$cart,
                            'transporteur'=>$nom_transporteur,
                            //'cart_products'=>$cart->getWsCartRows(),
                            //'customized_datas'=>$customized_datas,
                        )
                    ))
                )
            );
```

Can you help me with this please. I don't know what is wrong

**EDIT : When I remove this line, everything is fine :**

```
'order_details' => array(object(OrderDetail)),
```

and this is the line which product $order_details value :

```
foreach($liste_produits as $produit) $order_details[]=new OrderDetail($produit['id_order_detail']);
```

Comment: From serialize docs: `Note that many built-in PHP objects cannot be serialized`. So Maybe your `OrderDetail` has some reference to PDO? Maybe you better off just serializing database table columns info instead of whole object?

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how to do that but it seems a great idea :-)